# Call second time same action

Tags: servlets, redirect, struts2, action

When i fire first time action not displaing any error but after the first request i got this error.

my action call in jsp :

```
Search Action Class :
    public String search() {
        HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("sort", "1");
        dosearch(false, true);
        populateList(); // this method always populate formatList
        return "success";
    }
```

Struts config :

```
<action name="search" class="com.view.SearchAction"method="search">
            <result name="input" type="tiles">search</result>
            <result name="success" type="tiles">search</result>
            <result name="error" type="tiles">search</result>                               
</action>
```

root cause:

```
    tag 'select', field 'list', name 'selectedFormat': The requested list key 'formatList' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]

More on this error:

    org.apache.struts2.components.Component.fieldError(Component.java:230)
    org.apache.struts2.components.Component.findValue(Component.java:351)
    org.apache.struts2.components.ListUIBean.evaluateExtraParams(ListUIBean.java:80)
    org.apache.struts2.components.Select.evaluateExtraParams(Select.java:105)
    org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.evaluateParams(UIBean.java:856)
    org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.end(UIBean.java:510)
    org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doEndTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:42)
    org.apache.jsp.views.search_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fselect_005f0(search_jsp.java:1222)
    org.apache.jsp.views.search_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fform_005f0(search_jsp.java:765)
    org.apache.jsp.views.search_jsp._jspService(search_jsp.java:181)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:684)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:678)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:80)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:73)
    org.apache.tiles.context.TilesRequestContextWrapper.dispatch(TilesRequestContextWrapper.java:72)
    org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesRequestContext.dispatch(StrutsTilesRequestContext.java:88)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:283)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:154)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80)
    org.apache.jsp.views.shared.layout_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f2(layout_jsp.java:176)
    org.apache.jsp.views.shared.layout_jsp._jspService(layout_jsp.java:100)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:198)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:179)
    org.apache.tiles.context.TilesRequestContextWrapper.dispatch(TilesRequestContextWrapper.java:72)
    org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesRequestContext.dispatch(StrutsTilesRequestContext.java:88)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:606)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult.doExecute(TilesResult.java:105)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:361)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:265)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:148)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:93)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:128)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:104)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:148)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:128)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.akiyamag.interceptors.AuthenticationInterceptor.intercept(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:46)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:468)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:76)
    com.akiyamag.filters.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:106)
```

Comment: Where is your code for redirecting the page ?

Comment: The `formatList` is not a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type.

Comment: private List<CommonEntity> formatList;

public List<CommonEntity> getFormatList() {
  return formatList;
 }

public void setFormatList(List<CommonEntity> formatList) {
  this.formatList = formatList;
 }

Comment: @user3189778 Don't post the code in comments, edit your question and update the content. Also post JSP code as well.

Comment: Post your JSP. You might have using the different one .. You are not setting the value for `formateList` in your action class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already had your error. If i remind well the solution, the object formatList is either null or empty.

Comment: Empty collections don't generate exceptions.